# AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar is free or not for commercial use?

Tags: license

I know AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar is under Apple License.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions/Listings/README_txt.html

1. I wonder that AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar is free or not when it is included in commercial SW?
2. "In consideration of your agreement to abide by the following terms, and
   subject to these terms, Apple grants you a personal, non-exclusive
   license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the
   "Apple Software")"

In this question, I want to know the meaning of "personal".
Does it mean that it cannot be used for company?

Please let me know as possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I confess I'm not a legal expert, and don't fully understand the implications of that word; hopefully, someone will come along who is, and does.  But until then I don't think you need to be too worried, because the MIT licence starts

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any **person** obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction

Note the personal restriction there also; nevertheless, MIT-licensed software is used, copied, and modified by corporations every day.  I could go off on a discussion about [legal personhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_person), but I think the MIT licence text is the most convincing exhibit.

The Apple licence text allows licensees to "*to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute*" under conditions very similar to those of permissive free licences.  As I read it, you're fine to use the software.